# New to Django/Python and completely lost why my webpages are not linking

Tags: python, html, django, web

I am completely lost as to why my webpages are not linking.  They don't appear to be referencing the correct file paths ... I have tried to link the following 3 pages.

1. The homepage
2. The 'artists' icon on the top right of the homepage with the 'registerprofessional.html' so that when I click on 'artists' it takes me to the registration page
3. The 'customer' icon on the top right of the homepage with the 'registeruser.html' so that when I click on 'customer' it takes me to the registration page

I have added my code below:

1. home.html
2. registerprofessional.html
3. registeruser.html
4. file structure attached as image
5. registerprofessional error I get when clicking on the links added as images
6. register user error I get when clicking on the links added as images
7. urls.py
   Please let me know if I need to add anything else.

See code below:

1) home.html

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>ArtistsDecoded</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web/css/home.css">

        <!--  background image changer
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
        var i =0;
        var images = ['images/homepage/Arianna.jpg','images/homepage/vintagecam.jpg','images/homepage/10505026_413590265448462_3108080538408848321_o.jpg'];
        var image = $('#slideit');
                      //Initial Background image setup
        image.css('background-image', 'url(images/homepage/Arianna.jpg)');
                      //Change image at regular intervals
        setInterval(function(){  
            image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
                image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
                image.fadeIn(1000);
                });
                if(i == images.length)
                i = 0;
            }, 5000);  
             });
        </script>
        -->
    </head>

    <body style="background-image:url(/static/web/img/homepage/arianna.jpg)">
    <!--  background image changer not working  <div id="slideit" style="width:700px;height:391px;"></div>
         -->
        <div class="container">     
            <!--row 1-->
            <header class="row">    
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div id="title">
                    <p><a href="home.html"><i>ArtistsDecoded</i></a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-5"></div>


            <div id="loginbar">
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <div id="createprofile">
                        <p><a href="registerprofessional.html">Artists</a></p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <div id="signup">
                        <p><a href="registeruser.html">Customers</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <div id="help">
                        <p><a href="homepagebootstrap.html">Help</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <div id="login">
                        <p><a href="login.html">Log In</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </header><!--top bar-->

            <!--row 2-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
                <div class="welcome_text_div center-block">
                    <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                <div class="how_it_works_box text-center">
                    <a href="#" id="how_it_works">
                        How It Works
                    </a>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
                <div class="searchbardiv text-center">
                <form action="">
                <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                <select class="selectprofession">
                <option>What Are You Looking For?</option>
                <option>Hair Stylist</option>
                <option>Henna Artist</option>
                <option>Make-up Artist</option>
                <option>Photographer</option>
                <option>Videographer</option>
                </select>

                <input id="locationbox" type="text" placeholder="Where?"/>
                <input class="datebox" type="date" name="Date From?"/>
                <input class="datebox" type="date" name="Date To?"/>
                <input id="search" type="submit" value="Search" />

                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--container-->

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/web/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2) registerprofessional.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ArtistsDecoded</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/registertemp.css">



</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <div class="title"><i>ArtistsDecoded</i></div>

        </div>
        </div>

    <hr>


    <div class="container">

        <br></br>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form">


        <h4><img class="registerimage" src="Images/Registertemp/registertemp.jpg" alt="register" height="35px"></img><strong>Register Your Serices</strong></h4>
        <p>Be the first to know when we launch this site!<p>


        <form role="form">

            <div class="form-group">
            <Select name="Profession" multiple>
            <option>Select Profession*</option>
            <option value="make-up artist">Make-up Artist</option>
            <option value="mehndi artist">Mehndi Artist</option>
            <option value="hair stylist">Hair Stylist</option>
            <option value="photographer">Photographer</option>
            <option value="dhol group">Dhol Group</option>
            </Select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="firstname">First name:</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="surname">Surname:</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="sname" placeholder="Surname">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="number">Phone number:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone number">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="instagramid">Instagram ID:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="instagram" placeholder="Instagram ID">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="facebookid">Facebook ID:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="facebook" placeholder="Facebook ID">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="twitterid">Twitter ID:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="twitter" placeholder="Twitter ID">
            </div>

            <p class="selectinstructions">*Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.</p>

            <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox">I have read &amp; agree with the <a href="termsandconditions.html">terms and conditions</a></label>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" rel="contact_form1" id="contact_form1_button">Submit</button>

        </form> 




    </div><!--form-->
    </div><!--col-->
    </div><!--row-->

    </div><!--container-->

<script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>    
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
</body>


</html>
```

3) registeruser.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ArtistsDecoded</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/registertemp.css">


</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <div class="title"><i>ArtistsDecoded</i></div>

        </div>
        </div>

    <hr>


    <div class="container">

        <br></br>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form">


        <h4><img class="registerimage" src="Images/Registertemp/findservices.jpg" alt="register" height="35px"></img><strong>Looking for a Professional</strong></h4>
        <p>Be the first to know when we launch this site!<p>


        <form role="form">

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="firstname">First name:</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="surname">Surname:</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="sname" placeholder="Surname">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="number">Phone number:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone number">
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox">I have read &amp; agree with the <a href="termsandconditions.html">terms and conditions</a></label>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" rel="contact_form1" id="contact_form1_button">Submit</button>

        </form> 




    </div><!--form-->
    </div><!--col-->
    </div><!--row-->

    </div><!--container-->

<script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>    
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
</body>


</html>
```

[image: file structure]

5) Error - Registerprofessional

[image: Error - Registerprofessional]

6) Error - Registeruser

[image: Error - Registeruser]

7) urls.py

```
"""
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Add an import:  from blog import urls as blog_urls
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include(blog_urls))
"""
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'src.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: where do the links take you when you click on them?

Comment: Have you tried prepending a '/' infront of your paths so they become relative? i.e /registeruser.html

Comment: @TheoretiCAL apologies, have added the screenshots for the errors ...  About your second point, I have added the '/' and hit cmd+s (am on mac) ... it doesn't seem to be saving my changes. I can see this as I also changed the title and this didn't reflect either ... could this be the problem? A connection issue or am I missing something really simple do you think.

Comment: What do you have in your `urls.py` file?  I'd guess you have registered your URLs without the `.html` extension maybe ?

Comment: @bunnmatt added everything that's in the urls.py file above ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no URLs configured. Django can't handle a URL if you haven't told it how to handle them.

[Go to the tutorial, and follow it.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/)